# Use localstorage to hide alert div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following code on my page where you can close the alert using the X, but the alert shows up on every page refresh. How do I go about getting this alert to permanently be dismissed if that closebtn is clicked? I'm assuming I can use js localStorage but I'm new to all of this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="alertpilot rndcor">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;

<style>
.alert {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s; /* 600ms to fade out */
}
.rndcor {

    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
}
</style>


</span>
  Hi <?php echo $pilot->firstname?>! Come join our Discord Server to get the latest news and converse with other pilots. <a href="https://discord.gg/XXXXXX" target="_blank"><img src="http://crew.XXXXX.org/lib/images/joindiscord.png" style="box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)"></a>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {

window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alertpilot").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
}, 7000);

});
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm saying that I don't understand anything when it comes to javascript.. which is why I'm asking for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code to setItem and getItem for localStorage as

```
if(localStorage.getItem("show") !== "true"){
    localStorage.setItem("show", "true");
 }

$(document).ready(function () {

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        if(localStorage.getItem("show") !== "true"){
        $(".alertpilot").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            localStorage.setItem("show", "true");
        });
        }
    }, 7000);

    });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

window.setTimeout(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem("show") !== "true"){
    $(".alertpilot").fadeTo(1000, 0).slideUp(1000, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        localStorage.setItem("show", "true");
    });
    }
}, 7000);

});
```